# Updated question, please re-open if possible

Tags: support, reopen-closed

[How can I create a css background that is split in 2 halves, and goes in different directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665420/how-can-i-create-a-css-background-that-is-split-in-2-halves-with-different-color)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that by editing your question, it's automatically entered into the reopen review queue.

Comment: @icktoofay correct.

Comment: What if I say no?

Comment: Nothing I can do lol

Comment: You have triggered the Meta affect, and your post should be reopened within seconds.

Comment: I read your edited question, and based on what I see it's still not quite ready for SO (although it may not be a duplicate any longer, it's far from being an answerable question from what I read).

Comment: Your question shows absolutely no code and tries to link to jsfiddle, which gave you message telling you that you should include code in the question. But still you chose to "de-link" jsfiddle and not add code. Why is that, I wonder?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Because it's a giant piece of code.

Comment: @guisasso: then you should reduce it to what is *essential* to the question. If there's a giant piece of code, then no one will read through it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you edit the question within the first 5 days after it is closed, it will automatically insert itself into the Review Queue. That way others should be able to find it and vote to reopen if they so choose.

It does appear that you edited within this time frame, so if others decide your question is no longer a duplicate, it should reopen eventually.

Comment: It would be nice if it was displayed that if edited questions would be reviewed =]

Comment: @guisasso If you read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) it actually says that: *"Questions that are edited by the original poster within five days of being put on hold are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review."*